# Setting parallelism level in Akka from my program

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, jvm, akka

I recently switched a program I wrote from scala 2.9 to 2.11.  In the process, I moved my original scala Actor code over to use Akka actors.  Unfortunately, now the code I previously used to limit the resources consumed by the program no longer work.  Instead, now my program seems to take up all available processors on a system.  I know that I can write and bundle a custom configuration file to set the number of threads differently from the Akka default.  However, is there a programmatic way to tell Akka how many threads (or, more desirably, physical cores) to use?  It seems like there should be a simple API call for this, but I didn't seem to find anything in my quick look over the docs.  It would also be OK if there was simply a way to restrict the number of processors used at the level of the JVM, but I'm not sure this is possible either.  Any suggestions to how people usually solve this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override akka default config in runtime this way:

```
// use 1 thread at max
val dispatcherConfig = ConfigFactory.parseString("akka.actor.default-dispatcher.fork-join-executor.parallelism-max = 1")

// override default parallelism-max value
val defaultConfig = ConfigFactory.load()
val customConfig = ConfigFactory.load(dispatcherConfig).withFallback(defaultConfig)

// create actor system with custom config
val system = ActorSystem.create("system", customConfig)
```

More detailed documentation about configuration of akka dispatchers is avaliable [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/dispatchers.html).

Comment: Thanks; this is exactly what I was looking for!  It would have taken a while to sort it out combing through the large (but well-done) akka docs.